# setTimeout ignores delay in Android stock browser(Webkit 534.30)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, webkit, settimeout

We are having a weird problem since last month with `setTimeout` when executing our app in some devices with Webkit 534.30, from both android webview and stock browser. Our app is a jQueryMobile web app.

The setTimeout calls are ignoring the delay and the callback is executed immediately. These problematic setTimeout calls have worked correctly for almost two years, and keep working in every SO & Navigator except the last-mentioned Webkit.

```
var timerId;

function resetDisconnect(){
   if(timerId != null){
       window.clearTimeout(timerId);
   }

   timerId = window.setTimeout(function(){
       //Delayed code
       disconnect();
   }, 600000);
}

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
   resetDisconnect();
});
```

As you can see, **we are using an anonymous function** so that it's not evaluated in the setTimeout declaration and the delay value is hardcoded.

This is driving us crazy, the problem is that we use this timer to disconnect the user when he stays inactive(no server call) for 10 minutes, but in some devices with Webkit 534.30 the callback is executed immediately after the "ajaxComplete" event is fired.

Note that we haven't been able to reproduce this behaviour in our development environments.

What can make the setTimeout ignore the delay in this Webkit version?

We have noticed that all the setTimeouts of the app are failing in the devices where the above code fails, but we don't see any difference between environments that can make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [famous bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13540) for Android 2.* Stock Browser, it use `Webkit 534` build.

It was closed as `wrongforum` status. So, I think there is no issue to fix this. In Webkit Bug Tracker I don't find such bug.

Comment: I don't think this problem is related to the bug you point, the webkit version I mention is the stock browser from Android 4.0.1 to 4.3. They speak about older versions of android and we have no problem with them. http://jimbergman.net/webkit-version-in-android-version/